# Get the value between <> with dynamic number inside it

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

I am working on a text summarization method ,for test my method i have a benchmark called `doc 2007` ,inside this benchmark i have a lot of xml file ,i should clear that file .

for example i have a `xml` file like this:

```
<sentence id='s0'>
 The nature of the proceeding 

1 The principal issue in this proceeding is whether the Victorian Arts Centre falls within the category of 'premises of State Government Departments and Instrumentalities', for the purposes of provisions in industrial awards relating to rates of payment for persons employed in cleaning those premises.</sentence>

<sentence id='s1'>In turn, this depends upon whether the Victorian Arts Centre Trust, a statutory corporation established by the Victorian Arts Centre Act 1979 (Vic) ('the VAC Act'), is properly described as a State Government department or instrumentality, for the purposes of the award provisions.</sentence>
;
```

I should extract the string between `<sentence id='s0'></sentence>` and `<sentence id='s1'></sentence>` I mean the result should be like this :

```
The nature of the proceeding 

     1 The principal issue in this proceeding is whether the Victorian Arts Centre falls within the category of 'premises of State Government Departments and Instrumentalities', for the purposes of provisions in industrial awards relating to rates of payment for persons employed in cleaning those premises.

In turn, this depends upon whether the Victorian Arts Centre Trust, a statutory corporation established by the Victorian Arts Centre Act 1979 (Vic) ('the VAC Act'), is properly described as a State Government department or instrumentality, for the purposes of the award provisions.
```

I found some thing like this :

```
Regex.Match("User name (sales)", @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value
```

using `Regex`,but it doesn't work .could you please give me a fast solution to do that?

Comment: You have a *well*-formatted XML, why are you trying to parse it using Regex? Use XML parsers!

Comment: I am not familiar with xml parser

Comment: XML processing is a fundamental part of .NET since v1. You can use the old XMLDocument, the newer XDocument, XPath queries etc. You can even load an XML document inside a datatable. Web services (ASMX or WCF). You can't program in .NET without learning about the available XML classes. Regular expressions on the other hand are unsuitable for XML parsing, except for some very simple cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using LINQ to XML should be easier:

```
var res = XElement.Parse(xml)
                  .Descendants("sentence").Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "s0")
                  .FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

or, as Yeldar suggested, the cleaner way would be:

```
var s0 = XElement.Parse(xml)
                 .Descendants("sentence").FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "s0")
                 .Value;
```

Comment: the second sentences should be include

Comment: your answer just extract the first <>

Comment: Instead of `.Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "s0").FirstOrDefault()` it can simply be `.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "s0")` :)

Comment: I got this error :There are multiple root elements. Line 5, position 2. dear friend

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Most probably, there are multiple root elements :) A well-formed XML file should contain exactly one root element.

Comment: Your code just extract the first tag value between <sentence id='s0'></sentence> but i need the all of them i mean <sentence id='s1'></sentence>

Comment: @EhsanAkbar - just change the attribute value to `s1` and you will get the second string, then you can concatenate them etc.

Comment: I have 190 sentences inside my text ,you mean i should every time change it  ?

Answer (score 0):

XElment.Parse only use in String with single root node. The instance you wrote have two nodes '' without one root node.
You can add a root node like below:

```
xml = "<root>" + xml + "</root>";
```