# Get the value between <> with dynamic number doesn't work

Tags: c#, regex

I have an string like this :

```
<sentence id='s0'>
 The nature of the proceeding 

1 The principal issue in this proceeding is whether the Victorian Arts Centre falls within the category of 'premises of State Government Departments and Instrumentalities', for the purposes of provisions in industrial awards relating to rates of payment for persons employed in cleaning those premises.</sentence>

<sentence id='s1'>In turn, this depends upon whether the Victorian Arts Centre Trust, a statutory corporation established by the Victorian Arts Centre Act 1979 (Vic) ('the VAC Act'), is properly described as a State Government department or instrumentality, for the purposes of the award provisions.</sentence>
;
```

I need this output :

```
The nature of the proceeding 

     1 The principal issue in this proceeding is whether the Victorian Arts Centre falls within the category of 'premises of State Government Departments and Instrumentalities', for the purposes of provisions in industrial awards relating to rates of payment for persons employed in cleaning those premises.

In turn, this depends upon whether the Victorian Arts Centre Trust, a statutory corporation established by the Victorian Arts Centre Act 1979 (Vic) ('the VAC Act'), is properly described as a State Government department or instrumentality, for the purposes of the award provisions.
```

I should extract the string between `<sentence id='s0'></sentence> and <sentence id='s1'></sentence> .`

I asked this question here [Get the value between <> with dynamic number inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450153/get-the-value-between-with-dynamic-number-inside-it#) and the solution is like this :

```
var res = XElement.Parse(xml)
                  .Descendants("sentence").Where(e => e.Attribute("id").Value == "s0")
                  .FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

I have 190 sentences inside my input.
but this code just extract the first tag i mean :

```
The nature of the proceeding 

    1 The principal issue in this proceeding is whether the Victorian Arts Centre falls within the category of 'premises of State Government Departments and Instrumentalities', for the purposes of provisions in industrial awards relating to rates of payment for persons employed in cleaning those premises.
```

How can i extract all tags value ,i have 190 sentences inside my input

Comment: Just remove the `Where` - you are filtering for a specific element... then remove `FirstOrDefault` and you will get a collection type with all sentences. You can then loop (`foreach` etc)

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. Try to make your question clearer in the first time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
var res = XElement.Parse(xml)
    .Descendants("sentence")
    .Select(s => s.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

`res` will be an array of strings - inner contents of every `sentence` XML element.

For example, `res[0]` will be:

```
The nature of the proceeding 

1 The principal issue in this proceeding is whether the Victorian Arts Centre falls within the category of 'premises of State Government Departments and Instrumentalities', for the purposes of provisions in industrial awards relating to rates of payment for persons employed in cleaning those premises.

In turn, this depends upon whether the Victorian Arts Centre Trust, a statutory corporation established by the Victorian Arts Centre Act 1979 (Vic) ('the VAC Act'), is properly described as a State Government department or instrumentality, for the purposes of the award provisions.
```